# c - How do you accept a command line argument via redirection

Tags: c, stdio

If I have two command line arguments to my program like so

```
./program hey.txt hello
```

but I wanted to accept the first argument like this

```
./program hello < hey.txt
```

How would I be able to do that?

Comment: The `<` and `hey.txt` won't be seen by the program on Unix; the shell will interpret them as 'redirect standard input so it comes from the file `hey.txt`'.  It is not at all clear, therefore, what you are after.  At one level, there's nothing to do: if given one argument, the program can read from standard input.  If you're trying to do something else, you'll need to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

```
main( int argc, const char* argv[] )
{
    FILE* inputFile = NULL;
    if ( argc == 3 )
    {
       // I have 2 arguments. The first is a file name, the second is my other argument.
       inputFile = fopen( argv[1], "r" );
    } else if ( argc == 2 ) {
       // i have one argument so the input will come from stdin.
       inputFile = stdin;
    }

    // now read the file somehow.... like with fread.
    fread( inputFile );
}
```

Answer (score -4):

你可以使你的程序接受三个参数，可以通过判断第二个参数是什么来选择你的操作，就像这样

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    if (argv[2] == "<") {
        dosomethings;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

note:http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter10/arguments_to_main.html

Comment: I'm not sure what the ideographs say, but the code isn't accurate; either `hey.txt` (two argument invocation) or `hello` (one argument invocation) is found in `argv[1]`.

Comment: As noted by Johnathan Leffler, in a comment to the question, the shell will swallow the "< hey.txt" as a redirection and the program will never see it.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler "你可以使你的程序接受三个参数，可以通过判断第二个参数是什么来选择你的操作，就像这样" --> "You can make your program accepts three parameters, you can determine what the second parameter is to choose your operation, like this."

Comment: The `<` will not be seen by the program nor any `argv[]`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler shhhhh! "He who is most creative conceals his sources the best."